# How to package a python app that depends on another python package that includes a non-python CLI executable with pyinstaller

Tags: python, package, pyinstaller, executable

I have two python packages. Package A is a dependency of package B, and includes a CLI executable. This is the basic file structure of Package A:

```
PackageA
| CLIExecutable
  | executable.exe
| __init__.py
setup.py
```

The CLI is then called using the `subprocess` module.

I have these parameters set within Package A's `setuptools.setup` to include the CLI when packaged:

```
package_data={package.__name__: ["CLIExecutable/*"]},
include_package_data=True,
```

Package B imports Package A and uses it for some of its methods. When I run Package B as a python package, it works and is able to access the CLI that is included in Package A. However, when I package it using `pyinstaller`, it is unable to access the CLI and returns a `FileNotFound` error.

Comment: But that's the thing. Package B doesn't natively have the files for the CLI. It is trying to use them from Package A.

Comment: Hmm. So I need to include it in both packages? What would be the destination for the --add-data flag?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Pyinstaller has a `--collect-data` flag. I just needed to add `--collect-data=PackageA`